# Process data with JavaScript after AJAX call (CakePHP 2.6.x)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json, cakephp

I want to fetch data from a controller method and return the data as JSON string, so JavaScript can process it.

I performed all the steps so Cake can handle JSON as described [here](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html).

AJAX call in view:

```
$.ajax({
     url: '/cake/workers/getWorkersAsJSON.json',
     async: true,
     success: function(data) {
        console.log("data: " + data);
     }
});
```

Controller method:

```
public function getWorkersAsJSON() {
    $workers = ClassRegistry::init("Worker")->find('list', array( 'order' => array('fullname' => 'asc'), 'conditions' => array('Worker.partner_id' => '6')));
    $this->set('_serialize', array('workers'));
}
```

I expected the data in the `data` variable of JavaScript but this is always `null`.

When I add `return json_encode($workers);` to the controller, then I get the data but I don't think that this is the idea behind this whole setup.

What do I have to do so JavaScript gets the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `$this->set(compact('workers'))` to the action. Currently you are only setting `_serialize` which indicates which var to serialize but not passing the `$workers` var itself to the view.